# Redis: Finding the SCARD of an SINTER result without storing the intermediate set

Tags: python, lua, redis, redis-py

I need the length (SCARD) of the intersection of 2 large sets in redis.

So this achieves what I want:

```
> SINTERSTORE intermediate s:1 s:2
> SCARD intermediate
```

However the sets are large, so I don't want to store the intermediate value. Conceptually I want:

```
> SCARD (SINTER s:1 s:2)
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a single command, perhaps with Lua scripting? Or is my best bet to script it out in my application language and delete the intermediate value when I'm done? e.g. using python and redis-py:

```
>>> r = redis.Redis(...)
>>> pipe = r.pipeline()
>>> res = pipe.sinterstore('intermediate', 's:1', 's:2').scard('intermediate').delete('intermediate').execute()
>>> print res[1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis doesn't do nested commands so the conceptual version, while helpful to describe the need, isn't supported.

I suggest that you use the intermediate value approach, but instead of pipelining use a transaction (MULTI/EXEC) to wrap the intersect, cardinality and delete operations.

Comment: Right on, in my opinion.  Do note that in `redis-py`, the equivalent of `MULTI`/`EXEC` is actually wrapped into the functionality of pipeline objects (they have methods named `multi` and `execute` for that purpose).

Comment: @rchang thanks! after RTFMing I see that redis-py's pipelines are transactional by default #LearnSomethingNewEveryDay :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I will use the pipeline approach.